# Chain parent selectors with LESS from within selection?

Tags: css, less

I have multiple body classes and im hiding an element within these pages. When a class is added to the page with javascript then I want to show this element (assuming the body has these body classes).

This is working fine but can I rewrite it to avoid repetition?

```
.body-class-a,
.body-class-b,
.body-class-c {
  .element {
    display: none;
  }
}

.body-class-a.js-class,
.body-class-b.js-class,
.body-class-c.js-class {
  .element {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Normally I would do something like this. However its not working as `.infscrl-all-shown` isn't above `.body-class-a`, its on the same level.

```
.body-class-a,
.body-class-b,
.body-class-c {
  .element {
    display: none;
    .infscrl-all-shown & {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you would just need to remove the space between `.infscrl-all-shown &`.

In doing so, you are no longer selecting a descendant (since the space is removed between the class selector and the parent selector, `&`). The selector `.infscrl-all-shown&` will select the `.body-*` classes than also have the class `.infscrl-all-shown`.

```
.body-class-a,
.body-class-b,
.body-class-c {
  .element {
    display: none;
    .infscrl-all-shown& {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

It will output the following:

```
.body-class-a .element,
.body-class-b .element,
.body-class-c .element {
  display: none;
}
.infscrl-all-shown.body-class-a .element,
.infscrl-all-shown.body-class-b .element,
.infscrl-all-shown.body-class-c .element {
  display: block;
}
```